# Ignoring missing file error in ReSharper

Tags: resharper

There are some XML files in the project I'm working on that are included in the project files, but that don't exist (they weren't created by NAnt for some reason). The project is working fine, but ReSharper reports each of the missing files as an error. I know I can ignore ordinary errors, but with these, clicking on the `+` symbol in “Errors in Solution” does nothing, so I don't know how to ignore them.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an “Ignore Error(s)” button, just mark the errors you want to ignore and click that button.